# How can I get started with Perl 6?

Tags: perl, raku

Could someone provide a link of material where to start with Perl 6?
Also could  someone point to real application already developed with Perl 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to Zoran's assertion, dev.perl.org/perl6/ is out of date in many places.

I'd recommend the community-driven alternative instead: http://perl6.org/

The probably largest Perl 6 application today is the November wiki by Carl Mäsak and Johand Viklund:  http://november-wiki.org/

If you already know some Perl 5, this is a good place to start: http://perlgeek.de/en/article/5-to-6

If you don't know Perl 5, your best bet is a Perl 6 book currently in development: http://github.com/perl6/book/ (go to the download section and pick the latest .pdf there).

Answer (score 14):

[Rakudo](http://rakudo.org/) is the droid you're looking for. **Rakudo** is an almost completely working Perl 6 implementation, currently the best approach to Perl 6 you can get.

- You can [download compiled packages or build it from source](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo)
- [Perl 5 to 6](http://perlgeek.de/en/article/5-to-6) - Perl 6 for Perl 5 developers
- The [Perl 6 Wiki](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl6/index.cgi)

Comment: If you had a more extensive answer in mind, but withheld it because the question came from someone with a poor reputation, then please pretend that **I** asked the question instead. Otherwise, you're punishing others for one person's laziness or ignorance.

Comment: Good point, but I don't have more information than is available on Rakudo.org, no. But I can be more specific, will add links to the subpages. :)

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a good place to start... http://dev.perl.org/perl6/

Answer (score 3):

A nice resource (at time of writing) for people who already know Perl 5 is the  [Perl 6 Advent Calendar](http://perl6advent.wordpress.com/)